# Rails Helper Method To Build Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have adapted this from an example I had stored from a while ago(from railstutorial) but it's not working correctly:

I have **patients** that **have many** **hospitalizations**, and I tried to implement a **helper method to store the last patient searched and displayed**(on the show action) so that I could manage to create the new hospitalization for that patient through something like this:

```
@hospitalization = current_patient.hospitalizations.new(hospitalization_params)
```

And been trying to use these helper methods:

```
module PatientsHelper

  def current_patient=(patient)
    @current_patient = patient
  end

  def current_patient
    @current_patient
  end

end
```

And calling those on my patients_controller

```
  def show
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    current_patient = @patient
  end
```

Lastly I'm getting this error:

**undefined method `hospitalizations' for nil:NilClass**
Here is where the error points to:

```
  def create
    @hospitalization = @current_patient.hospitalizations.new(hospitalization_params)
    if @hospitalization.save
```

at hospitalizations_controller.rb

I wanted to know why it's not recognizing "current_patient" as an instance of the Patient's Model. Am I doing something wrong on my Model or calling it at the wrong place in my Controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you have `include PatientsHelper` in your controller?

Comment: Where is it not recognizing `current_patient`? In a view?

Comment: I have included PatientsHelper in my ApplicationController, and it's not recognizing it in a view, yes. When I try to submit hospitalizations#create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to persist the `current_patient` from one request to another. This is only possible by passing params or by storing the patient in the session. This is how I would do it:

```
def current_patient=(patient) 
  session[:current_patient_id] = patient.id
  @patient = patient
end

def current_patient
  return @patient if @patient && @patient.id == session[:current_patient_id]
  @patient = Patient.find(session[:current_patient_id])
end
```

This is probably a little more code than just storing the current_patient instance on the sesison, but it's better to save less data on the session—like *just* the id as opposed to the whole instance.

Comment: You could, of course, just put these methods right in the ApplicationController and call `helper_method` directly.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as if I included PatientsHelper in my ApplicationController?

Comment: Yes, totally the same. Just a matter of style or preference. I like to see helper methods like this in the ApplicationController (or whatever controller) since they're fairly important and not too many lines.

Comment: I see, I had already included it in my ApplicationController, and now tried your code from PatientsHelper returning me the following error: **undefined method `helper_method** I've read that 'helper_method' can only be declared on ApplicationController, is that right? Even tho, doing that I still get the error mentioned in my question.

Comment: I believe included was a typo? Because replacing with 'included' it gets back to the same situation I got with all the other options.

Comment: I tried something like this earlier, but the error was another: **Couldn't find Patient without an ID** what I'm now knowing the right way to do is to get the patient_id from my patients#show and making it available to my hospitalization#create

Comment: Can I do something like this in Patients#Show:

Hospitalizations.set_current_patient = @patient ?

Comment: Patients#show and Hospitalizations#create are two different requests and so you'll either have to pass params in the request and look up based on params... or... you could set the current_patient on the session. `session[:current_patient] = @current_patient`

Comment: Thank you very much, the session trick nailed it. If you would like to update something about it in your answer? So I accept it.